# Make synchronous http request with React Native

Tags: react-native

I know synchronous requests are not a good practice and I always try to avoid them. But in this case I must use an external library that uses synchronous http request and I don't want to get to the point of modifying third party code.

According to [React Native DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network), the XMLHttpRequest API is built in to React Native, but when i try to use it I get `Synchronous http requests are not supported`.

[image: Error message]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using fetch with async/await for http requests. XMLHttpRequest synchronous is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) in the javascript world, so it is in react native

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey
>   2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know this functionality is deprecated, but as I mentioned it is used in an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your code if you're calling a HTTPS request in it. I fixed my code by removing that piece of code. Hope this will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).